# OpsWorks Instances Shutting Down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, instance, aws-opsworks

I have three stacks on Amazon Web Services OpsWorks. As an instance, there is a "Rails App Server". When I try to stop it, it just says "stopping" for hours. Does someone know this bug or problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: When I consider all structure of OpsWorks, from EC2 I deleted the Volumes before stopping, now I don't know what I will do here.

Comment: Happened to me too, I had to ask for help in an AWS forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue in Opsworks - when instances cannot be stopped or removed due to permission changes, volume removals, etc. You can request them to be removed in AWS forum. Post the problem, instance id and stack id: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=153&start=0 and AWS admins monitoring the forum should pick it up.
You'll need to be logged in with your AWS account in order to access the forums.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like something looping.

Try check your shutdown run list recipes.